# How to tell if I visited an untrusted website that contain viruses?

Tags: windows-7, website, firefox

I just want ask, how we can know if we just visit untrusted website contains viruses? I browse the internet every day for my job and use many websites and accounts. I'm afraid that someone will be steal my data. I use Windows 7, Antivirus AV Free edition (always updated), and the newest Mozilla FireFox browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run reputable AV and Spyware utilities, try not to visit shady websites, and do not download anything you do not trust.  If your AV or Spyware pops up with a message when visiting a site, pay attention to it, but it might also be a false positive.  If something is flagged when I am surfing, I typically Google it.  Many times you can determine the validity of the warning by doing a bit of simple research on the site.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox has inbuilt feature to block an untrusted website. However Google also do the filtering for you as I have taken two screen shot for a site with Google search and without Google search I tried to redirect that site but not success because FF inbuilt feature blocked me to do that.

[image]

[image]

And rest will do your AV as I have installed Eset and I tried to access an illegal site and it blocks me to  do that cause its not safe for my PC.

[image]

Also you can use [TrustGauge](http://www.trustgauge.com/). You will be able to find other programs that give each site a ranking and will allow you to know if they can be trusted. But these programs are not fool proof but they can help protect you much of the time.